# simple calculator in java parser

Tags: java

I am currently making a simple calculator parser in Java, to deal only with + and - operators, and whole numbers. I have read about [postfix](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/postfix-evaluation/index.htm) and [infix](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/infix-postfix/index.htm) evaluation, and I am wondering if brackets can be used with either of these methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The beauty of the postfix/prefix notation is that you do NOT need the brackets. Brackets are used in infix notation because there are ambiguities, e.g:

```
a + b - c
```

This can mean either of the following:

```
(a + b) - c
a + (b - c)
```

However, in postfix notation, they are clearly different:

```
a b + c -
a b c - +
```

There is no need for parantheses/brackets to enforce evaluation order in postfix notation.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

---

#### Conversion from infix

You can take an expression in infix notation with parantheses and convert it to postfix notation, obeying operator precedence. One such algorithm is Edsger Dijkstra's stack-based "shunting-yard algorithm".

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned with the simple math operators + and - which are commutative then you probably do not need to care about parenthesis which usually enforce the order of computation.

Your calculator might only need to be a simple parser and accumulator that ignores parenthesis if present - unless I'm missing something about the intended meaning of the parenthesis

Comment: I'm not sure what commutativity has to do with the issue. Especially since `a - b` is not the same as `b - a`. That is, `-` is NOT commutative.

Comment: My bad. What I meant to say was that the + and - ops are associative

Comment: Guess he meant to say (a + b) - c = a + (b - c), for + and - operations parenthesis are meaningless (ignoring rounding errors for floating point operations)